# Token Holder History By Date Query In Dune Analytics

Tags: cryptocurrency, erc20, dune, dune-analytics

I'm trying to create a simple query for a token in Dune Analytics. The purpose of the query is to show token holder history by date.

Here is the code. Can anyone fix it?

```
SELECT
  DATE_TRUNC('day', evt_block_time) AS date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT account) AS num_holders
FROM erc20."ERC20_evt_Transfer"
WHERE contract_address = '0x430ef9263e76dae63c84292c3409d61c598e9682'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

I tried to write a query that would show token holder history by date. It didn't work.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Spare us the drama. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the contract address here is varbinary datatype. So there's no need of including it in the single quotes. Try removing it and it may work!